# Updating ListView JsonParsing by using Volley

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I'm getting the json response in logcat window, which does not update the listview. When I set breakpoints in the addcontent() method, first time it doesn't get json,but third time it does(I stepped over few times in the debug perspective window). Below is my Adapter

```
public class DaibeticRegAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter{
private Context mContext;
//DiagRegPojo pojo = new DiagRegPojo();
DiabeticRegJson drJson = new DiabeticRegJson(); 
public DaibeticRegAdapter(Context c){
    super();
    this.mContext = c;        
    drJson.addContent();       
    }
@Override
public int getCount() {     
    return drJson.getName_list().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drJson.getName_list().get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View view = convertView;
       if(convertView==null)
       {
           view = new View(mContext);
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diagnostic_reg_list, null);
           TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.diabetic_reg_item);      
           System.out.println("ArtraYlist Size fom Adapter"+drJson.name_list.size());
           System.out.println("Array LIst Options"+drJson.getName_list().get(position));
           textView.setText(drJson.getName_list().get(position));

       }else{
           view =(View)convertView;
       }    
       return view;
       }    
}
```

and this is a Java class to parse Json by using volley

```
public class DiabeticRegJson {
String tag_json_arry = "json_array_req";
String TAG  = "TESTING";
String diag_url= Urllist.digRegJson;
private static final String DIAG_REG_NAME = "content";    
public static final String savedCookie = "savedCookie";

public ArrayList<String> name_list=new ArrayList<String>();


public  ArrayList<String> getName_list() {
    return name_list;
}
public  void setName_list(ArrayList<String> name_list) {
    this.name_list = name_list;
}    

public void addContent() {        
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(diag_url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {
                        //name_list.clear();
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            String diagName = person.getString(DIAG_REG_NAME);                    
                            name_list.add(diagName);                               
                            //pojo.name_list.add(diagName);
                            Log.i("VOLLEY GETTING URLS", diagName); 
                            Log.i("VOLLEY GETTING URLS FROM ARRAYLIST", name_list.get(i));  
                            }                           
                        System.out.println("Size of List " + name_list.size());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();                            
                    }                   
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());   
                    Log.i("ERROR JSON PARSING", error.getMessage());
                }
            })
            {            
       //**
        // Passing some request headers
         //*
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Cookie", MainActivity.sharedpreferences.getString(savedCookie, ""));                
            headers.put("Set-Cookie", MainActivity.sharedpreferences.getString(savedCookie, ""));
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
            //headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
            return headers;
        } 
    };   
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_arry);
    }
    }
```

Plz let me know what is missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be a logcat can help ?

Comment: "first time it doesn't get json,but third time it does" can you explain it further.

Comment: I'm getting json in Logcat, during execution of addcontent() method

Comment: @mmlooloo., Yes just I set a breakpoint in the first line of addcontent() method, then stepped over few times. first two times it comes out of onResponse() method without json response and the third time it  goes inside the onResponse() method with json response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not notifying your adapter when new data is retrieved, so it's not updating the UI.  To fix it with your existing code you could pass a reference of your `BaseAdapter` to `DiabeticRegJson` and call `BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` it from your listener after you set the response.

The other option would be to use an `ArrayAdapter`, and let that manage your `String` list for your -- and just add the Strings to the adapter rather than having your request object encapsulate the response.